# Parse a String containing a JSON array to an Object

Tags: java, gson

I succeeded to parse my object to a JSON array string :

```java
public class MyClass extends JsonElement {

    private JsonArray array;

    public MyClass(String name, String role, String title) {
        this.array = new JsonArray();
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(name));
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(role));
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(title));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement deepCopy() {
        return array.deepCopy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isJsonArray() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonArray getAsJsonArray() {
        return array;
    }

}
```

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass obj = new MyClass("ab", "cd", "ef");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj)); // "["ab", "cd", "ef"]"
```

How can we do the opposite ?

```java
MyClass obj2 = gson.fromJson("[\"ab\", \"cd\", \"ef\"]", MyClass.class);
```

I got :

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a MyClass but was com.google.gson.JsonArray

I tried :

```java
public class MyAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, CommunityTeamMember value) throws IOException {
        TypeAdapters.JSON_ELEMENT.write(out, value);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        JsonArray array = TypeAdapters.JSON_ELEMENT.read(in).getAsJsonArray();
        return new MyClass(array.get(0).getAsString(),array.get(1).getAsString(),array.get(2).getAsString());
    }

}
```

```java
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done some trickery by making your object behave as a JsonArray to the serializer, so you get a JsonArray back, but the deserializer only knows to put it into a JsonArray.  To get back an instance of the class you had, you can add a constructor that takes a JsonArray

```
class MyClass extends JsonElement {
    private JsonArray array;

    public MyClass(String name, String role, String title) {
        this.array = new JsonArray();
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(name));
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(role));
        this.array.add(Objects.requireNonNull(title));
    }

    public MyClass(JsonArray jsonArray) {
        this.array = jsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement deepCopy() {
        return array.deepCopy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isJsonArray() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonArray getAsJsonArray() {
        return array;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyClass obj = new MyClass("ab", "cd", "ef");
        String serialized = gson.toJson(obj);

        System.out.println(serialized); // "["ab", "cd", "ef"]"
        MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(JsonParser.parseString(serialized).getAsJsonArray());
        System.out.println(obj2.getAsJsonArray()); //["ab","cd","ef"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use `JsonParser` because the json array I try to parse is in a json object :
{
  "str": "abc",
  myclasses : [ ["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["gh", "ij", "kl"]
  ]
}

Comment: It helps if you fully specify what you need.  What's the reasoning for using it as a JsonElement anyways?  Why not just serialize the class directly?

Comment: The `MyClass` object is a field in another class, and it's this class I want to desrialize. In fact, using it as a JsonElement change nothing.